# Show existence of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let us **fix** any three numbers in $[0,1]$ and summing up to $1$. I denote them by $p_1, p_2, p_3$.

Could you help to show that, for every possible vector of reals $U\equiv (U_0, U_1, U_2)\in \mathbb{R}^3$, there exists a random vector $\epsilon\equiv (\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$ continuously distributed on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the following equalities hold:
$$
\begin{cases}
p_1=Pr(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0\geq U_0-U_1, \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2\geq U_2-U_1)\\
p_2=Pr(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_0\geq U_0-U_2, \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2\leq U_2-U_1)\\
p_3=Pr(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0\leq U_0-U_1, \epsilon_2-\epsilon_0\leq U_0-U_2)
\end{cases}
$$

(Note that the distribution of $\epsilon$ can vary across values of $U$)

---

This question is related to a problem of identification in econometrics.

I have tried to prove it by construction as follows (I also highlight where I'm stacked).

**Step 1:** Consider any  $U$.

**Step 2:** Suppose I'm able to show that there always exists a random vector vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\eta_A\\
\eta_B\\
\eta_C\\
\end{bmatrix}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_U, \Sigma_U)
$$
such that
$$
\begin{cases}
p_1=Pr(\eta_A\geq U_0-U_1, \eta_B\geq U_2-U_1; \mu_U, \Sigma_U)\\
p_2=Pr(\eta_C\geq U_0-U_2, \eta_B\geq U_1-U_2; \mu_U, \Sigma_U)\\
p_3=Pr(\eta_A\geq U_1-U_0, \eta_C\geq U_2-U_0; \mu_U, \Sigma_U)
\end{cases}
$$
(I'm actually not able to show that).

**Step 3:** This is the hardest step. How do I show that there exists $\epsilon\equiv (\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0\\
\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2\\
\epsilon_2-\epsilon_0\\
\end{bmatrix}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_U, \Sigma_U)
$$
?
The issue here is that I'm considering differences of random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, note that we only ever look at the differences between the various $\epsilon_i$'s. That means that we can safely set $\epsilon_0 = 0$ without changing anything. The same goes for $U_0$.

We get:

$$\begin{cases} Pr(Y=1) &=& Pr(&\epsilon_1 &\geq& -U_1 &,& \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2 &\geq& U_2 - U_1&)\\Pr(Y=2) &=& Pr(&\epsilon_2 &\geq& -U_2 &,& \epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1 &\geq& U_1 - U_2&)\\Pr(Y=0) &=& Pr(&-\epsilon_1 &\geq& U_1 &,& -\epsilon_2 &\geq& U_2&)  \end{cases}$$

Let's inspect the last two of these a bit closer.
If $\epsilon_2 \geq -U_2$ **and** $-\epsilon_1 \geq U_1$, then $\epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1 \geq U_1 - U_2$; so that means we're in the case $Y=2$. We'll just have to make sure that the conditions for $Y=0$ cannot hold at the same time!

Well, we're in luck. We just need to make sure that $-\epsilon_2 < U_2$, which means that $\epsilon_2 > -U_2$. Given our assumptions, that just means that $\epsilon_2 \neq -U_2$, which is easy enough to accomplish.

We can do the same for the first and third cases combined. We find that if $\epsilon_1 \geq -U_1$ **and** $=-\epsilon_2 \geq U_2$, we have the case that $Y=1$ and should not also have that the conditions for $Y=0$ are satisfied. We get that $\epsilon_1 \neq -U_1$.

Combining the first two cases is also interesting. We get that we should not have $\epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2 = U_2 - U_1$.

We have to look at 3 cases. If both $\epsilon_1 > -U_1$ and $\epsilon_2 > -U_2$, their difference will decide which case we're in. If both $\epsilon_1 < -U_1$ and $\epsilon_2 < -U_2$, we're in the case $Y=0$. There is a region where we have no valid case (unless $U_1 = U_2$) but that's easy enough to compensate for.

Have a look at the interactive graph at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xtmn9xowwi where you can play around with the values. Just take a subset of the 2-dimensional plane that contains part of each of the 3 regions, and set the appropriate probability to each.

Comment: Thanks. Consider some of the events we don't like: $\epsilon_2=-U_2$, $\epsilon_1=-U_1$, $\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2= U_2-U_1$. Since $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ are continuous random variables by definition, aren't these zero probability events? Hence, they have measure zero and we don't need to worry about them. Also, can we repeat the argument with $\epsilon_0$ not degenerate equal to zero? I know the systems are equivalent, but I want to make sure that there exists a proper three-dimensional random vector satisfying my restrictions.

Comment: Correct. It's just that, when constructing our own distributions just to show they exist, it is sometimes convenient to use that particular kind of subset (turning a continuous space into a discrete space. So I felt the need to specify that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that is a formal proof of existence.

Comment: I think that, as long as you show that those 3 regions are not empty (they are not) you can easily show that a distribution must exist.